# Has Logan aged considerably in the new movie Logan?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, wolverine, marvel, logan

In the new trailer we see Logan at the very end holding hands with a girl (sorry I don't know who she is), also throughout the clip we see his beard and there are quite a lot grey hairs in it:

### Has Logan aged considerably?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

There are hints in the trailer, particularly part of Logan's voiceover:

> Logan: Charles, the world is not the same as it was. Mutants, they're gone now.

that strongly imply that a lot of time has passed since the last time we saw Logan (chronologically, the end of *Days of Future Past*). In addition, the movie itself is based heavily on the Marvel comic story "Old Man Logan", which tells the story of Logan in a distant dystopian future.

Lastly, the writers [have explained](http://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/logan-trailer-breakdown-james-mangold-talks-us-first-teaser/) the reason behind Logan's scars as being an effect if his age:

> So we questioned whether Logan’s healing factor causes him to heal without even a scar. We imagined that it may have when he was younger, but with age, he’s getting older and ailing.

Comment: That is what I was looking for UV